# What is the safe/proper way to run non-metallic conduit between floors?

Tags: building-regulations, fire-hazard, data-wiring, conduit

I need to run a CAT5 line and a 22/4 alarm wire from my 2 story attic to the first floor.  I have access to the interior of the walls (I will re-dryboard).  I'd like to run carlon ENT from the attic all the way down so I can run new wire if needed.  What is the connection I need to travel between floors to keep it up to fire code?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you looking for how to run a connection through a bottom plate? What fire code applies and how to meet it?

Comment: That's right (didn't know the wording for bottom-plate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your locality, and you didn't mention where you are. In my locality, I think the only necessary plug between floors is to use some fire-stop expanding foam insulation on the outside of the ENT. (For those not in the know, ENT = Electrical Nonmetallic Tubing, aka interior flex conduit.)

Your local city/county building inspector / permit office will know more, and you should contact them.

Comment: region=California. So is there some specific Carlon couplings I should be using, like a vertical stub?

Comment: Yeah, but it's going to depend on what provisions of the NFPA Code, IEC, and IRC your city and/or county has adopted. There isn't a special fitting. You just want to seal any excess opening to keep air from moving between floors easily. In a fire, the the Carlon tubing would perform similarly to PEX, and I know for a fact in my area that the provision for PEX penetrations is that you should use fire stop spray foam.